# How to minify ES2016 or convert to ES2015 in flask?

Tags: flask, babeljs, flask-assets, webassets

I'm using [flask-assets](https://flask-assets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and none of the available filters (rjsmin, jsmin, closure_js, uglifyjs, etc.) is able to minify a ES2016 JavaScript file. The minified files yield errors on the browser console (due to bad conversions) or even crash on execution before serving the resources. 
Also, I have tried Babel filter from [webassets](https://webassets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/builtin_filters.html#javascript-cross-compilers) and I it doesn't make any change on the files, they are just served without changes.

I also can't manage to enforce the closure or babel extra_args to customise their operation.

Any tip or recommendation?

Example code:

```
from flask_assets import Bundle
page_js = Bundle(
    'js/code_with_es2016.js',
    filters='rjsmin',
    output='public/js/code.min.js'
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use the babel filter with `babel-presets-env`. The webassets documentation is a bit behind on the recent developments which is no surprise considering how fast things are moving in the javascript world.

So first you will need to install `babel-cli` globally:

```
npm install -g babel-cli
```

Now you will need to install `babel-preset-env` locally, so within your project directory do:

```
npm install --save babel-preset-env
```

Finally this is how to set up your bundle with `flask-assets`:

```
from flask_assets import Bundle, Environment
from webassets.filter import get_filter

assets = Environment()
assets.init_app(app)
babel = get_filter('babel', presets='babel-preset-env')
assets.register('js_all', Bundle(
    'js/code_with_es2016.js',
    output='public/js/code.min.js',
    filters=[babel, 'rjsmin']
))
```

You can also tell babel where your `babel-preset-env` is installed by specifying the absolute or relative path to it:

```
preset_location = './path/to/node_modules/babel-preset-env'
babel = get_filter('babel', presets=preset_location)
assets.register('js_all', Bundle(
    'js/code_with_es2016.js',
    output='public/js/code.min.js',
    filters=[babel, 'rjsmin']
))
```

And one last thing, and this is only (like) my opinion, I would highly recommend switching over to javascript/node based build process for your frontend assets (you are using babel already!). Depending on what you are developing gulp or webpack can be good candidates to use for your frontend build.  Flask-assets/webassets just seem unnecessary because they're lagging behind with docs and package versions of whatever the latest and greatest in the frontend world is.

Comment: The problem now (I already had this problem and I couldn't solve it as well) is that it can't find the preset because it expect it to be installed on the same folder of the manage.py and its a few folders away from this file.
`"Couldn\'t find preset "babel-preset-env" relative to directory" `
Is there any way to point it to the preset?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to set path to babel preset.